# Notepad++ have marker with both icon and background color

Tags: c#, notepad++, scintilla

I am working on a Notepad++ plugin in C#. For this I want a marker to be set which has both a margin icon (pixmap) and a colored highlighted line. In my attempts so far, it seems I can only get one of them working:

```
Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERDEFINEPIXMAP, MARKER_CURRENT_POS, Image);
```

or

```
Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERDEFINE, MARKER_CURRENT_POS, (int)SciMsg.SC_MARK_BACKGROUND);
Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERSETBACK, MARKER_CURRENT_POS, 0x00ff00);
Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERSETFORE, MARKER_CURRENT_POS, 1);
```

Is it possible to have both?